# Plugin redmine insert on action into project_menu in init.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to insert into project menu method view issues when tracker="bug".If I want insert view issues.this code:
Redmine::MenuManager.map :project_menu do |menu|
  menu.push :tracker1, { :controller => 'issues', :action => 'index' }, :param => :project_id, :caption => :label_issue_plural
Now I want It only show issues when it 's tracker="bug".What?
Can You help me????

Comment: I insert:Redmine::MenuManager.map :project_menu do |menu|
  @trackers.each do |tracker|
    menu.push :tracker.name, { :controller => 'issues', :action => 'index',:set_filter => 1,:tracker_id=>tracker.id }, :param => :project_id, :caption => tracker.name
  end
 end

Comment: but i meet error:undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)